# Substract one array from another

Tags: php, arrays

Well, I have

```
$a2 = array('a'=>'Apple','b'=>'bat','c'=>'Cat','d'=>'Dog','e'=>'Eagle','f'=>'Fox','g'=>'God');
$a3 = array('b','e');
```

I want to substract $a3 from $a2 to get:

```
$aNew = array('a'=>'Apple','c'=>'Cat','d'=>'Dog','f'=>'Fox','g'=>'God');
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($a3 as $value){

   if(isset($a2[$value]))
         unset($a2[$value]);
}
```

Comment: It's a better one, like the array_key_exists check.

Comment: This check is unnesesary and it will be slower

Comment: And, anyway, `isset` better than `array_key_exists`

Comment: `foreach($a3 as $value) isset($a2[$value]) && unset($a2[$value]);` but, as i said before, it's absolutely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

the are two built-in functions to do something similar: [array_diff](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_diff_assoc](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) - but both won't work in your case.

so, to do what you want, you'll have to change the markup of your `$a3` a bit to fit these functions (take a look at the documentation), or you'll have to loop `$a3` and delete the elements from `$a2` manually like this:

```
foreach($a3 as $k){
    unset($a2[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't get it.

```
$aNew = $a2;
foreach($a3 as $key) unset($aNew[$key]);
```

you need this one?

Comment: Thanks,  thought there might be some inbuilt function of php

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with php built-in functions.

Since the array `$a2` contains the values of the *keys* you want to remove, you need first to create an array containing the values of `$a2` as keys using `array_flip`. Then you can just use `array_diff_key`. So try this:

```
$aNew = array_diff_key($a2, array_flip($a3));
```

Note that you need php > 5.1.0 for this to work.

Comment: yeah? I thought the built-in functions where really fast. Should not matter if you only have a few elements though.

Comment: Just test it on my local comp, just to be sure - 100k iterations with `flip` is about 0.56sec and with `foreach` 0.46sec

Answer (score 0):

```
$aNew = array();
foreach (array_diff(array_keys($a2), $a3) : $key) {
   $aNew[key] = $a2[key];
}
```

This sould do the job. Grap the keys from a2 remove all keys which exist in a3 and then copy the remaining keys to a new array. You could also remove the keys from the old array. This is up to you.

Edit: +$

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here lies in that you compare *key* of one array with *values* of another one. E.g. by the use of array_diff_ukey.
Excerpt from PHP manual:

```
  function key_compare_func($key1, $key2)
  {
     if ($key1 == $key2)
       return 0;
     else if ($key1 > $key2)
       return 1;
    else
       return -1;
```

}

$array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
$array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

var_dump(array_diff_ukey($array1, $array2, 'key_compare_func'));

array(2) {
  ["red"]=>
  int(2)
  ["purple"]=>
  int(4)
}

Your second array is not associative, so this would compare "a" with 0, e.g.
So it's:

```
$compareFunc = function($key) uses ($a3) {
 if(array_key_exists($key, $a3) {
    return true;
 }
 else return false;
}

array_map($compareFunc, $a2);
```

can't be used neither, because this function is used to modify but not to reduce the array.

```
$a4 = array();
$compareFunc = function($key) uses ($a3, &$a4) {
 if(array_key_exists($key, $a3) {
    array_push($a4);
 }
}
```

would do the job.

**What I am trying to achieve is:
Play around with the PHP - functions that provide callbacks to you when the standart - functions don't succeed.
Try using the concept of binding, when the describtion of the callback doesn't fit your needs. With PHP's Lambda - functions you can bind objects / variables to a function,
so that you have access to variables that are not passed to the callback.
Get creative!!!**

Answer (score -2):

Try using [array_diff](http://my.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
but you need to make some changes on your $a3.

```
$a3 = array('bat', 'Eagle');
//and then
$a4 = array_diff($a2, $3);
```

because without specifying a key (in `key => value` format), the string will automatically become a value instead.

Comment: and if you cant change input arrays (coming from outside for e.g.)? Not a good idea